# Autodesk autocad dimensions?

Tags: autocad, autodesk

How do I add this annotation? It is a dimension between two lines but it is angled. By default it draws it straight out from the points.[picture of what i need to draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkB0A.jpg)

Comment: Another, easier, approach is to make a dynamic block which includes the dimension lines and import it with command asking for the parameters of the slotted hole. Then this alignment is automatically done.

Comment: If I understood you, the angled dimension is a matter of Dim Style, where you can specify the angle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the command **DIMALIGNED** for this, with a perpendicular osnap.

If you want to create it with the .NET API, you need to create an `AlignedDimension`. There is a constructor where you pass 3 points (line1 & line2 points + dimension line point), the dimension text and the dimension style.